# Fatigue modelling in Abaqus

Tags: abaqus, fatigue

## My problem:

I'm trying to model fatigue disbond growth in Abaqus. So far I've tried this using multiple approaches with mixed results.

## What I've tried:

I first started with modelling a static general step. I've tried:

- Interaction with fracture properties, I was not able to propegate a crack:

  - both with and without a "debonding with vcct" crack under interactions-> specials-> crack
  - both with and without material defined with traction seperation damage
- Interaction with cohesive behaviour with damage, I was able to propegate a crack:
- X-fem with material defined with traction seperation damage, I was able to propegate a crack:

  - both using no contact property and a vcct fracture property

I was initially hoping to use the debond using vcct because it seems like the thing to use for my case but I've set that aside for the time being.

I then moved on to modelling fatigue using a direct cyclic step. It's not something I've used before so I might have done this incorrectly. I've tried to figure it out using tutorials as well as reading the documentation but I'm not sure it's correct. The settings I used are:

- cycle time period: 1 (standard setting)
- incrementation: both automatic and fixed
- increment size: ranging from 1 to 0.05, I've figured out that this is the step size one cycle is modelled in, but I'm not sure how the accuracy of this relates to the fatigue modelling
- maximum number of iterations: 5 (instead of 200 in order to save computational time)
- number of fourier terms: have not touched this
- max allowable temperature change per increment: 1 to 1e-5 I think this is used to choose the optimum step size, not sure what a reasonable number is
- fatigue: I include low level cycle fatigue analysis
- cycle increment size: anything from 10 to 1000
- maximum number of cycles: anywhere from 1000 to 100000
- damage extrapolation tolerance: 1 I have no idea what this does so I haven't touched it

I've created an amplitude with:

- frequency 6.28 (loading and unloading once per cycle)
- starting time 0
- initial amplitude 0.5
- A 0
- B 0.5 (combined with the intial amplitude this should mean the loading is from 0 to 1 I think)

Unfortunately I have not been able to get the cohesive interaction to disbond under fatigue loading. I think I might be supposed to change some of the keywords, but I've not been able to change them successfully.

The x-fem approach did work with the fatigue loading. However, I originally did this using a velocity constraint. When I switched to loading or a displacement constraint the crack did not propegate, even with loads significantly higher than the case with the velocity constraint.

## Where I'm currently at:

I've got a model that sometimes cracks when using a direct cyclic step using X-fem with a vcct interaction. I'm very confused and don't know what I could try next.

## My question:

How can I fix my model such that I can model disbonding under fatigue loading? I understand helping like this might not be easy so any resources that you could point me towards would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Create a "table" of all options or settings and change each to see the effects - getting a suitable working model takes a lot of effort, and based on my experience it is not a "one hit wonder`'...

Comment: @SolarMike thank you for suggestion. I have made a table of all combinations I thought would be logical and I've exhausted that. I suspect I'm missing something fairly obvious (I'm relatively new to using Abaqus or any other FEM software for that matter).

Comment: Changing to a dynamic implicit timestep seems to have helped